# How to see change on remote repo, which not in local repo?

Tags: python, git, github

I'm executing a command 'git push' and get error.
My remote repository is ahead of the local one.
I want to find out what changes have occurred on the remote repository.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't want to pull those changes yet, you can accomplish this with `git log`. First run `git fetch` to update your local refs. Then you'll want to run `git log my-branch..origin/my-branch`. This will show you commits on origin/my-branch (i.e. remote), which do not exist in your local repository.

Comment: Strange. I didn't make any changes on the remote repository. But I can't to push.
"Your branch and "origin/master" have split
and now have 121 and 16 different commits in each, respectively."

Comment: Has someone else pushed to your master branch? Sounds to me like someone else pushed or did a rebase of your master branch.

Comment: I am the only one working in this branch.

Comment: So `git log --pretty=format:"%an <%ae>" origin/master | sort -u` shows only you? I ask this because by default GitHub repos are public and it doesn't set up protected branches for you, meaning literally anyone can push to any branch on your repository. Also, did any other commits show up in the log command I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: 1. AlexShemyakin <64311224+AlexShemyakin@users.noreply.github.com>
2. AlexShemyakin <fax777@rambler.ru>
fax777 - it's my email. 
What is the different between 1 & 2?

Comment: The first is your github email and the other is the email associated with your git client. They are different, but it's still clearly you. Does `git fetch` provide any output?